# Creating an image overlay in javascript / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently attempting to write a JavaScript application that when certain conditions are met, will automatically

```
Open some sort of window (Ideally border-less)
Window displays an image
Window is able to be clicked through
Window displays over all other applications
Ideally window can also handle transparency
```

Does anyone know how I might go about this?
Essentially I'm trying to create an overlay via a Node.JS application running locally on my Windows 10 Machine.
If attaching an overlay to an application would be easier that is also something that could work for what I need to do as well.

I've searched for hours to try and find a solution to this. Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do that with electronjs.